# Conversion from Hibernate to Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, linq, hibernate, entity-framework-6

what is the entity framework equivalent of ToFuture() and BeginTransaction()

Comment: Please state clearly what you need help with

Comment: what is the entity framework equivalent of ToFuture() and BeginTransaction()

Answer (score 0):

For Transaction

```
ctx.Database.BeginTransaction()
```

For Future & FutureValue

There is no equivalent of “Future” directly in Entity Framework.
However you can achieve the same result through third party library

- http://entityframework-plus.net/
- https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended (Unsupported, support moved to EF+)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project EF+ on github.